# Get SharePoint lists from URL

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, custom-fields

I want to receive the lists from a specific site URL. I know how to get the lists from the current site, but **what if it is a custom site URL**?

Here is how I do to get the lists from the current site:

```
foreach(SPList list in SPContext.Current.Web.Lists)
{
    DdlLookupFieldTargetList.Items.Add(list.ToString());
}
```

an example og my input string could look like this: http://dkbdkb70la/sites/HelloWorld

I am using SharePoint 2007

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're given the url you want to open directly, it's a simple matter:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(inputStringUrl))
{
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
    {
      DdlLookupFieldTargetList.Items.Add(list.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```